# php regular expression...weird behavior

Tags: php, regex

What's wrong in this expression?

```
echo preg_replace("/Condizioni/","ciao","<tr bla vla Condizioni");
```

It does not return anything...

Anyway It works when I remove "<" char...but I don't understand why...is it a special char, and if so what I i have to do to match it literally.

Thank you...

Comment: Put the php code within back ticks or format it as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It work as you want ([code on ideone](http://ideone.com/hrNpk)). The only thing is that `echo "<tr bla vla ciao";` in a web page will cause troubles. You have to escape your HTML chars.

[`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) will do that for you :

```
echo htmlspecialchars(preg_replace("/Condizioni/","ciao","<tr bla vla Condizioni"));
```

It will echo `&lt;tr bla vla ciao`.

Answer (score 1):

How do you mean "return"?

```
$ php --version
PHP 5.3.2 (cli) (built: Aug  7 2010 00:04:41) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
$ cat test.php 
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?
echo preg_replace("/Condizioni/","ciao","<tr bla vla Condizioni");
?>
$ ./test.php 
<tr bla vla ciao
```

This looks correct.

What were you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the regex; it's just that the text with a `<` symbol will not display properly because the browser thinks you've opened an HTML tag.

You can prove this by doing "view source" on the browser; you should see the text as you expected it.

What you need to do is do htmlentities() on the finished text before you output it, so that the `<` character is escaped into an entity value that the browser can display.

Comment: I'll check Colin Hebert's answer only because He was the first...I'm sorry...thank you anyway...If it would be possibile to check more than one answer I would check the your one too...

Comment: @cubob - you can only tick on answer, but you can still up-vote multiple ones if they all helped.

Comment: I know...but I still cannot do it as I don't have 15 reputation...sorry